# WPF no inicia WCF al ser instalado

Tags: wpf, wcf

Tengo un WPF con referencias a un WCF configurado que funciona bien. Al debuggear con el Visual Studio, el "WCF Service Host" me dice que dicho servicio esta iniciado y no presenta problemas. Si lo consulto, me responde bien.

El problema es que cuando instalo el WPF en la misma pc, el WCF no levanta.

Intenté:

- Copiar las lineas del App.config del WCF al WPF para ver si lo levanta, pero sin cambios.
- Crear el ServiceHost por código y agregar todos los ServiceEndpoints pero no estoy pudiendo agregarle los behaviors y los bindings del ServiceModel.

Lo ideal seria no tener que duplicar el código del Config del WCF, a la programación del WPF.

Gracias, saludos!

---

EDIT:
Ya pude hacer cambios en la programación y crear el ServiceHost, agregar los ServiceEndpoints, el servicio de metadata, behaviors y endpoints, y el serviceDebug. Con esto ya funciona creandolo por código, pero tengo que checkear que no esté debuggeando ya que el visual studio lo inicia automáticamente.